# Why Doesn't Ajax and SweetAlert Show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, sweetalert

Please help me, in my code, Ajax and SweetAlert worked perfectly, but now I get the error on pressing submit:

The Google chrome console shows below error:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   application/javascript:
>   "http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{!! asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') !!}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var id1 ={!! $data !!};
        var hasil;
        var saldo ={{$results}};

        $('#jumlahUang').keyup(function () {
            var yeah1 = parseInt($('#jumlahUang').val());
            var yeah = parseInt($('#jenisTransaksi').val());
            if (yeah == 1) {
                hasil = saldo + yeah1;
            } else {
                hasil = saldo - yeah1;
            }

            if (hasil < 0) {
                swal("Error", "SALDO ANDA KURANG");
            } else {
                $('#debugg').val(hasil);
            }
        });

        $('#formInput').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id1 ={!! $data !!};
            var link = "/nambahTransaksi/" + id1.id;
            swal({
                title: "Konfirmasi transaksi",
                text: "proses transaksi?",
                type: "info",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#1da1f2",
                confirmButtonText: "Yakin, dong!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            }, function () { //apabila sweet alert d confirm maka akan mengirim data ke simpan.php melalui proses ajax
                $.ajax({
                    url: link,// ini salah anjing
                    type: 'get',
                    data: $('#formInput').serialize(), //serialize() untuk mengambil semua data di dalam form
                    dataType: "HTML",
                    success: function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            swal({
                                title: "transaksi berhasil dilakukan",
                                text: "Terimakasih",
                                type: "success"
                            }, function () {
                                window.location.href = "/detailTransaksi";

                            });
                        }, 2000);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            swal("Error", "Tolong cek kembali SALDO anda");
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What have you changed since yesterday?

Comment: I didnt change anything

Comment: I have read some answer frok another website but it doesnr work

Comment: @bramastavikana can you add a console.log to output the response in both the error and success callbacks? If your swal isn't showing something isn't right here and you have poor error catching right now making it harder to determine why.

Comment: My swal is working in another function i think ajax is not working

Comment: So add the output to see why haha

Comment: Are you getting an errors in your console?

Comment: Whre do i put my console log, sorry im new at this

Comment: Noo theres no error messge in console chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this js files,i hope its work for you.

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

example

```
$("#sub").click(function() {

var startDate = $('#fromDate').val();

var endDate = $('#toDate').val();

if (startDate !='')
{
    if(endDate == '')
    {
        swal("Error!", "Please Select To Date field", "error");

        return false;
    }

}
else
{
    swal("Error!", "Please Select From Date field", "error");

    return false;
}

if(startDate > endDate)
{
    //alert("Please Select To Date Grater Than"+startDate);
    swal("Error!", "Please Select To Date Grater Than "+startDate, "error");
    return false;
}  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line set to be a stylesheet but it is actually a .js file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{!! asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') !!}">
```

Try using:

```
<script src="{!! asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') !!}"></script>
```

Also, why are you including JQuery twice? Just move your second declaration to the top, the line that says:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

It needs to be declared before you add SweetAlert because SweetAlert is dependent on it.

EDIT: This is only a partial answer. OP still has another issue outside of this. Wanted to leave this up however as it was useful in solving part 1 of his problem.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME typeapplication/javascript: "http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" its gone but ajax still doesnt work